# SQL Override error in Informatica Pushdown : Column Name list has less columns than Select

Tags: informatica

I am getting following error while running session in informatica. I am using Query in SQL Override and I have checked it has same number of columns as the defined in source definition and qualifier.
Can anyone suggest possible solutions?

(-3706)Syntax error: Column name list shorter than select list., SQLSTATE [37000]

Comment: You can't have the same number of columns in your select and source qualifier if you are getting this error

Comment: I do have. There is column that is not being read while creating pushdown view but I don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: can you pls run the SQL - dump in the XL - and then compare column order and data type between XL and the informatica SQ - if you see any differences.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I checked coulmn order and data type is same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: are all ports in and out of source qualifier linked ? to the previous and next transformation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try not to use query override, if possible.
2. Run the mapping without override. Verify the result.
3. GENERATE the SQL statement and run the mapping. Verify the result.
4. Compare the generated query against your own.
5. Verify the links going OUT from Source Qualifier.